# Where do I set the discount value on PayPal payments with the rest API?

Tags: java, api, paypal, reset, discount

I'am using the PayPal rest API with Java for doing payments with PayPal.
The payment method is set to "paypal" and the indent to "sale".

When an order has an voucher the total amount is smaller than the subtotal. 
I'm setting the total amount, the subtotal, the shipping cost and an itemlist. This all works but where can I set the value of a possible discount?

Is this possible with the rest API or should I use the classic API?

Thanks
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible in either API classic or REST. The classic api documentation says:

> Note: The Enter gift certificate, reward, or discount link enables the buyer to redeem certificates, rewards, or discounts that PayPal issues. The link does not enable the buyer to redeem incentives that you issue.

So that only applies to paypals own incentives and not your own which is what I expect you want.

However the REST API for payments found here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-payment only specifies a shipping_discount as read here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#details-object

Not 100% sure but you could possibly include a transaction object with a negative amount and give it the description discount.

```
"transactions":[
    {
      "amount":{
        "total":"10.00",
        "currency":"USD",
      },
      "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
    },
    {
      "amount":{
        "total":"-1.00",
        "currency":"USD",
      },
      "description":"10 Percent Discount"
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
"transactions": [
        {
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "Item",                    
                "price": "10.00",
                "currency": "AUD",
                "quantity": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "10% Discount",                    
                "price": "-1.00",
                "currency": "AUD",
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        },
        "amount":  {
            "total":  "9.00",
            "currency":  "AUD"
        },
        "description":  "Total"
    }]
```

It works for me like this.

[image]

Comment: The REST API does not allow negative values.  This works for me with the classic API, but not REST.

Comment: Now its working for me!!!!  Not sure what I changed / did wrong.  I'll re-up-vote the answer is SO will let me.